# What does "flag weight" on the user profile mean?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, flag-weight

On my [user profile](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3114/gerikson) there's a text string saying

> flag weight 110

What is the significance of this?

Comment: there is also a badge for this, "deputy" -- http://photo.stackexchange.com/badges/73/deputy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an value that shows how reliable your flagging is, and is related to the [new flagging system](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/).

For an in depth explanation see the [meta.stackoverflow.com question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) about this topic.